# How to convert Mat to cvMat in OpenCV 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I convert an OpenCV `Mat` object to `cvMat` object ?

As per this OpenCV interoperability document([1](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/interoperability_with_OpenCV_1/interoperability_with_OpenCV_1.html)), this conversion should be possible. But  on declaring `cvMat`, compiler gives below error message at line `cvMat deprecatedImg`

> : error: < expected ‘;’ before ‘deprecatedImg’ >,

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In OpenCV 3 and above you have to use compatability headers(`types_c.h`) for using deprecated C objects like `cvMat`. In OpenCV 3.0, `CvMat` has a constructor which accepts a `Mat`([1](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.0.0-beta/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h#L434)). Code as below.

```c++
#include "opencv2/core/types_c.h"
cv::Mat img = ... ;
CvMat deprecatedImg(img);
```

In OpenCV 2.4.* and below, `Mat` to `CvMat` conversion operator([2](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.11/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp#L387)) exists and you can simply assign a `Mat` to `CvMat` as below. Note that this conversion operator no more exists in OpenCV 3 and above.

```c++
Mat img = ...;
CvMat cvMatImg = img;
```